# New web programming language, creating a Compiler [Flex / GNU Bison]

Tags: bison, lex

I'm creating a new web programming language and I really want it to go through, now I know many things about web and sockets and HTTP requests and responses. All I need is your help guys with the Flex and Bison (it will be based on C++)

I'm not that good when it comes to creating compilers, so I don't know where to begin, because what I want to create a sort of semi-compiler, something like JVM, where all it does is create a bytecode classes that will run faster..

In fact, I even need someone expert in compiling to help me figuring out what compiling idea would be the best...

So my question is : Can you guys guide me to very helpful articles or tutorials to begin with? If you're interested can you join me and clarify things to me maybe?

The ideas I'm coming up are great, and I would really not stop because there's Java EE or PHP out there ^^

Comment: Great?  Sounds ridiculous.  And quite unnecessary.

Comment: I vowed to throw this at every would-be language designer, so here I am: [Programming Language Checklist](http://colinm.org/language_checklist.html).

Comment: Oh my, 'ridiculous'? I didn't even talk about it, I'm sorry for not being a "stick-to-what-we-already-have" type of guy !

Comment: Good Luck with this enormous task.   -1

Comment: `I'm not that good when it comes to creating compilers` there are not many people who are good at it either. "Programming Languages and Compilers" is a professional field in CS, my friend is getting his PhD in that area as we speak. You can't write a compiler overnight. I'd suggest you start by learning context-free grammars and finite-state automata, and then move on to lexical analyzers and parsers.

Answer (score 3):

There's an awesome class on creating compilers on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) - [Compilers](https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers), led by `Alex Aiken`. You can sign up for self-study.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples in the Net, how to use `lex` and `yacc`/`bison`.

Don't use keyword `flex`, when seaching examples. You will get adobe flex pages if you do so.

Here are something for beginners:

- [Step by Step guide for writing translator](http://ashimg.tripod.com/example.html)
- [Getting started guide for using Lex and YACC](http://ds9a.nl/lex-yacc/cvs/lex-yacc-howto.html)